# Is it possible to stream the response text from a LLM?

Tags: botframework

I'm creating a chatbot using Azure Bot Framework that can proxy user input to LLM, and then return the response from LLM to the user. My question is, is it possible to use Bot Framework to create streaming responses like those on the ChatGPT website?

I viewed the samples in https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=-samples-question.md but could not find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to get a response stream from your LLM (e.g. Semantic Kernel form Microsoft has a method that returns the completion answer bit by bit) you basically have two options:

1. Send out an activity to the user as soon as you get the first response piece and modify the sent out activity for each piece you get from your model. There ist the `Context.UpdateActivityAsync(...)` Method you can use. This basically posts updates to existing chat messages. Keep in mind, this only works with certain Channels if you are using Azure Bot Service. (check out this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 first table right column "Message update"). You might need to implement you own consumer of your Bots message endpoint. This is definitely an option and the api is not that complicated.
2. Send out an activity to the user as soon as you get the first response piece and simply send out further activities as soon as you get more pieces from the LLM. This will look like multiple chat messages to the user when you look e.g. in the webchat but usually you'll end up implementing your own frontend anyways so you are in charge of handling this messages. You also might want to collect some pieces before you send them out because sometimes you get te response character ba character and that would lead to many chat activities. In our solutiuon I'm collecting at least 20 characters and send them out as one activity.

One Idea we are currently following is to use another azure funcition to connect a SignalR service that kind of pushes the pieces towards the frontend.

Hopefully this helps. Happy coding :-)

Comment: How did the SignalR service implementaion workout. THinking about the same approach. DId you go for a hybrid approach (directLine and SIgnalR together) of everything via SignalR

Comment: @Hessel Would appreciate if you have some code for this

Comment: think you mean @Sven

Comment: It went well. We are using it in our solution. Unfortunately I cannot provide code but imagine it like this:


Bot -> Azure Function Http Trigger (Bot needs to post it's messages somewhere -> SignalR -> Frontend -> signalR -> Azure function signalR trigger -> Bot